# How to set layout properties of data flow using BIML?

Tags: ssis-2012, biml

Every thing is liner in my package which is making it look very thin and tall with so many tasks in it. Is it possible to set layout of tasks like width, height and position from BIML? so I can make it in good looking shape?

I can logically separate tasks into smaller groups with packages and containers but the least one I get could be on an average 20 DFTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Biml describes the elements that exist within the [SSIS object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403344.aspx). That model doesn't have entries for [spatial layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtsobject.aspx) of tasks and components nor does it contain anything for Annotations. Since neither of those exist in the object model, the emitted SSIS packages won't have them either.

The same would be true if you were using EzAPI or the base integration services library to construct your SSIS packages.

Comment: That said, if you find you have too many tasks in an SSIS package and it's becoming hard to visualize everything the package is doing, perhaps your design could use some tweaking. I find it helpful to reduce a package to the minimum it needs to do to solve task *X* and then composite the execution of all my little packages together to solve the grander business problem

Comment: Even after the logical separation I will have at least 20 tasks in it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by object model doesnt have entries for spatial layout. I can see this in xml code of a package `<NodeLayout
          Size="140,42"
          Id="Package\Employee Addressess \Source Stage"
          TopLeft="342,75" />
        <EdgeLayout
          Id="Package\Employee Addressess.Paths[OLE DB Source Output]"
          TopLeft="409.5,117">` I am sure package has layout saved in xml which is a big headache for diffing packages

Comment: That is designer specific information that has nothing to do with the [object mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtsobject.aspx) If you look through that documentation, there is nothing in there for the spatial positioning of executables. There's precedent constraint but that's it. The layout is purely to enhance the design experience within visual studio.